# JavaScript OnClick function do not call after its been called once

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

i have a function which is called on a onclick. Now it has to be on a onclick as thats when the data is being brought in.. i want to know how i can get it to disable and not be called after its been called once.

```
function Compare(){
    var OldVariants = Variants();
    var RequestVariants = ProductRequests();

    RequestVariants.forEach(function(req) {
        OldVariants.some(function(variant) {
            if (variant.Id == req.Id) {
                variant.Quantity(req.Quantity);
                return true; // Stops the inner loop
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve with jQuery [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) like so:

```
$(document).one('click', '#element', function() {
    // your code..
});
```

Now, your function will fire only for the first click on #element

Answer (score 0):

In your function, unbind the click event. Ex:

```
button.onClick = function({ 
    button.unbind('click');
}
```

Comment: I'm travelling and using mobile to ans, so not sure I can update that much. But can you try once before asking complete solution? Just pass reference of element on which click event is bind. You haven't given enough code also for us to understand.